# How to use the js variable in Cfquery

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, cfquery

This is the js Function , I need to use the "DataFileImportID" variable inside the Cfquery.

JS Code

```
<cfoutput>
    <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function Validate(DataFileImportID)
     {
        var DataFileImportID=DataFileImportID;
         alert(DataFileImportID);
        <CFQUERY name="get" DATASOURCE="HeliosMaster">
            select top 1  Description 
            from CDSDB01.dbo.BenchmarkReject  
            WHERE   Filemasterid ='#DataFileImportID#' and Description='Invoice totals do not 
 match loaded charge totals'
        </cfquery>
        alert("tets1");
        alert(get.recordCount);
        return confirm ("test");
     } 
    </script>
</cfoutput>
```

Coldfusion Code:

```
<cfif isPower eq 1>
<td align=center>
    <a href="./files/fileBenchmarkApprove.cfm 
      DataFileImportID=#DataFileImportID#&action=A" 
     onclick="Validate(#DataFileImportID#)">
   <img src="/x2intranet/images/approve16x16.jpg" width="16" height="16" 
    alt="Approve" border="0"></a> &nbsp;
</td>
</cfif>
```

Comment: Your javascript variable exists on the browser.  Coldfusion runs on a server.  You'll have to send that variable to the server.  One way to do that is with AJAX.  Another is to make the JS variable a form or url field and have the user do something to call a CF page.  Having said that, when I look at your code, I see no need for javascript at all.

Comment: See also https://blog.adamcameron.me/2012/10/the-coldfusion-requestresponse-process.html

Comment: @DanBracuk
 I need to show the popup when i click on the link, Before showing the popup i need to check some condition, SO i have return that query in Javascript, Which gives me a result. I have to use that javascript variable in the query at where condition.

Comment: Please read the link above. It explains why javascript variables can't be used in CFQuery's.